# The existence of a solution to $A\mathbf{x=d}$ with $x_i \in [0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i =1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ b an $m \times n$ matrix. I want to find the conditions that must be imposed on the matrix $A$ and the vector $\mathbf d\in \Bbb R^m$ such that there exists a vector $\mathbf x\in \Bbb R^n$ with entries $x_i \in [0,1]$ satisfying:
$$
A\mathbf x = \mathbf d\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i =1 \\
$$

Comment: Sorry, it is my bad. Each x_i is between 0 and 1. In addition, the summation of x_i's is equal to 1. In other words, x is a probability measure.

Comment: Clearly, the constraints $x_i \leq 1$ are redundant. Essentially, your problem is equivalent to the feasibility problem of a linear program of the form $A'x' = d'$ and $x' \geq0$, where$A'$, $x'$, and $d'$ are augmented. Farkas' lemma can useful in this context https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma

Comment: Thanks!  Of course, Farkas' Lemma solves everything